# Animation/position of vertices or faces controlled by another object's position relative to it

Tags: animation, constraints

So I'm trying to artificially enhance a 3D objects look to look more 2D, by having certain parts of the geometry shift in specific positions when the camera is facing those faces/vertices from specific angles to it.

To explain in an easier to word and grasp way:
Think of a random character
When the camera is facing from the left, the characters eyes look up and smiles,
When camera is facing from the front character has closed eyes and frowns
Etc

However when the character is faced from the front, but the head is turned to the side so that the characters face is viewed from the left, the behavior for the face displays the animation/position displacement for "camera on the left" while the body (the parts faced from the front) would display the position displacement/animation behavior for "camera facing the front"
If this makes any sense?

Comment: Please include a Blender screen capture in this and all future questions to improve the clarity of the question.

Comment: Please place a clear question in the above text even if you think the question is implied. A question with a question mark.